# SQL left join- slowing on smaller table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, left-join, sql-server-express

Using SQL Server Express. I have a master table of sales transactions that keeps the history of all sales transaction data. This table updates daily to add a new line capturing any changes to the sales transaction.

From this table, I have two views created - one for `Sales_Closed` and one for `Open_Bookings`. Each view returns the exact same column set, only the data is filtered respectively.

When I `select *` from each, the following occurs:

- `Bookings_open` - runs in 1 second, returns ~28,000 rows.
- `Sales_Closed` - runs in 4 seconds , returns ~200,000 rows.

Additionally- I have created a table to capture all combinations of relevant data needed for my final output, a report showing open bookings and closed sales 1 year back and 1 year forward. The columns from this table titled `Work_Template_month` are:  UPC, Location, Channel, sales type, Month, Year and fiscal year.

Running `Select *` from this table returns:

- `Work_Template_month`- runs in 23 seconds- 1,995,552 rows (wowzers, and yes it does need to be this big because I am doing more than described in later parts of the SQL)

So now the fun: if I run this SQL query here, and interchange (line 14)

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.bookings_open AS E
```

with

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.sales_closed AS E
```

`Sales_Closed` runs in 23 seconds

`Bookings_open` runs in **3:00**!!!!

Why would the smaller table take 8 times as long?!

```
SELECT       
    D.upc, 
    D.sales_type, 
    D.channel, 
    D.month, D.year, D.fiscal_year,
    D.adj_location,
    SUM(E.qty_sold) AS Sales_Qty, 
    SUM(CAST(E.total_adjust_dollars AS money)) AS Sales_Dollars
FROM            
    dbo.work_template_month AS D 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.bookings_open AS E ON D.upc = E.upc 
                           AND D.sales_type = E.sales_type 
                           AND D.channel = E.channel_name 
                           AND D.month = E.shipped_month 
                           AND D.year = E.shipped_year 
                           AND D.adj_location = E.adj_location
GROUP BY 
    D.upc, D.sales_type, D.channel, 
    D.month, D.year, D.fiscal_year,
    D.adj_location
```

Execution plan:
`Open_Bookings`:
[open_bookings_execution_plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkZU-t127)

`Sales_Closed`:
[sales_closed_execution_plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1-brF1nm)

Comment: Usual questions: Join predicate columns indexed in both tables?  Stats up to date? Share the execution plan?

Comment: @user1443098 I am using SQL Express, so I believe I am limited to the indexes the optimizer sets? Stats are updated-yes. Added execution plan to main thread.

Comment: No, you can set up normal indexes on tables. The plan does not have your table names.  Are you joining a view to a view (normally a bad idea)

Comment: @user1443098 in views as well?

Comment: The doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017 mentions no limitations for indexed views and express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the view for  `Open_Bookings` to make a table (with the exact columns) now called `Open_bookings_tbl`.

I replaced line 14 with:
`LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.bookings_open_tbl AS E`

This now runs in 19 seconds and I am still perplexed, happy but perplexed. Execution Plan below.

[Bookings_table_Execution_Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Skc-g2yhQ)

Answer (score 0):

Your join criteria is the problem

```
ON D.upc = E.upc 
                           AND D.sales_type = E.sales_type 
                           AND D.channel = E.channel_name 
                           AND D.month = E.shipped_month 
                           AND D.year = E.shipped_year 
                           AND D.adj_location = E.adj_location
```

IF the join was on a Primary Key to a foreign key wit would be better instead you are querying on several fields thats why the executuin has a hashed lookup in it.
Try adding covering indexes to the sales_type,Channel_month_year, and adj_location